# How to use DragPan while drawing a box using DragBox OpenLayer?

Tags: openlayers

I want to use drag pan (ol.interaction.DragPan) while drawing a box (ol.interaction.DragBox) so that I can select the area which are currently not in viewport. Is there any way to do so?

With jsfiddle example, I am able to draw a drag box but don't know how to use drag pan with it.

here is  [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opsaharan01/vhkeuzdv/)

```
 // a DragBox interaction used to select features by drawing boxes
  var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly
  });

  map.addInteraction(dragBox);

  dragBox.on('boxend', function() {
    // features that intersect the box are added to the collection of
    // selected features
    var extent = dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent();
  });
```